# $D \overline{D}= \mu$ for a complex matrix $D$ and a scalar $\mu$ implies that $\mu$ is real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following question arose while reading Kevin Buzzard's notes on "Forms of reductive algebraic groups", available [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/maths/research/notes/forms_of_reductive_algebraic_groups.pdf).

Let $D \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ be a matrix such that $D \overline{D} = \mu$ for a scalar $\mu \in \mathbb{C}$.  Here the right hand side denotes the scalar matrix obtained by multiplying the identity by $\mu$.  Buzzard claims that $\mu$ must be real.  His reasoning is that $\overline{\mu} = \mu$, but I don't see why this is true.  If you apply complex conjugation to both sides of $D \overline{D} = \mu$, you get $\overline{D} D = \overline{\mu}$, but I don't see why we must have $D \overline{D} = \overline{D} D$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Applying the conjugate transpose to $D \overline{D}=\mu$ gives $D^t \overline{D}^t = \overline{\mu}$.  But I see no reason why we must have $D \overline{D} = D^t \overline{D}^t$.

Comment: My bad. I think what does work is taking the trace though, since $AB$ and $BA$ have the same trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $D \overline D = \mu$ tells you that $\overline D = \mu D^{-1}$. Scalar matrices commute with everything and $D$ commutes with $D^{-1}$, so $D \overline D = D(\mu D^{-1}) = (\mu D^{-1}) D = \overline D D$.